# C++ Linked List using Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class:

```
typedef struct Listable
{
    struct Listable *next;
    struct Listable *prev;

    // Lots of other class members not pertaining to the question excluded here
} Listable;
```

and I inherit from it like so:

```
typedef struct Object : Listable
{
} Object;
```

Problem is, when I do something like this:

```
Object *node;
for (node = objectHead; node; node = node->next);
```

I get an error with 'node = node->next', since node->next is of type Listable, while node is of type Object.

How can I use templates in the Listable base class to make the prev & next pointers change their type to the class being used?

Perhaps something like:

```
typedef struct Listable<T>
{
    struct Listable<T> *next;
    struct Listable<T> *prev;

    // Lots of other class members not pertaining to the question excluded here
} Listable;
```

and I inherit from it like so:

```
typedef struct Object : Listable<Object>
{
} Object;
```

I have over 10 years of C, but am fairly new to C++ features like templates. So I'm not sure what syntax I should be using.

Comment: Yes, I realize that these objects can only belong to one list at a time. This is by design.

Comment: Just so you know there is a built in linked list

Comment: No need to use `typedef struct` in C++. `struct` alone is sufficient.

Comment: This method is faster than the built-in linked list.

Comment: The best way to define your list type is to separate it completely from the type it must hold: don't make a "listable" class which turn other classes into lists through inheritance, but make a container with list specific operations (add, remove, catenate). This will reduce your class complexity and avoid interferences between the list interface and the contained type.

Comment: Besides, if you need to implement lists of lists (...), you will have to specialize your code.

Comment: Good advice, although in this particular situation here I need to eliminate the overhead of having a container. By using the inheritance method, it restricts functionality, but offers speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template syntax itself is fairly straight forward:

```
template <typename T>
struct Listable
{
    T *next;
    T *prev;

    // Lots of other class members not pertaining to the question excluded here
};
```

So, when it gets inherited by `Object` like this:

```
struct Object : Listable<Object>
{
};
```

`Object` will get the `next` and `prev` pointers.

Since `Listable` is managing pointers, you will need to pay attention to the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/315052). That is, you have to think about what needs to be done during destruction, copy construction, and assignment so that memory is managed properly.

Comment: I try this, but get a compile error, 'typename' : is not a 'struct'
(talking about the next and prev declarations)

Comment: @user1054922: Sorry, should be fixed now. [Works on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0FPwMZ).

Comment: A big THANK YOU for directly answering my problem without telling me to use std::list, etc. I would give you more points if I could.
Seems I'm having some issues now with the Add/Remove member functions not liking a base 'Listable' class as parameter, but the template syntax was the crux of my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you would rather not just use:

```
Listable *node;
for (node = objectHead; node; node = node->next);
```

instead? That would work even if node is actually an Object, because Object inherits from Listable.

Also, as Jerry mentions, there already is a built-in [templated, doubly linked list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) that is part of the C++ Standard Template Library. You would not need to manually write a for loop either, because you could also use [std::foreach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) [to operate on it](http://ideone.com/q8ZOOl):

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Sum {
    Sum() { sum = 0; }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }

    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};

    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());

    std::cout << "sum: " << s.sum << '\n';
    std::cout << "elements:  ";

    //Or, you could use iterate over each node in the list like this
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflating the notion of of a linked list with that of a node *in* the linked list. Then you're adding in an `Object` that (supposedly) is one of these confused node/linked list things. At least to me, this sounds quite confused and confusing.

I'd prefer to see something like:

```
template <class T>
class linked_list { 
    class node {
        T data;
        node *next;
    public:
        node(T data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}    
    };

    node *head;
public:
    void push_back(T const &item);
    void push_font(T const &item);
    // etc.
};
```

Caveat: of course, for real code you 1) probably don't want to use a linked list at all, and 2) even if you do, it should probably be a `std::list`.